# How do I recursively rename files in a directory with Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script which appends " - Confidential" to the end of files that don't already match the string "Confidential" within the filename. When running this script in the directory, it works. However, I need it to rename all the items within the subfolder too. How could I achieve this?

```
    Get-ChildItem * -Exclude *Confidential* -Recurse | 
  ForEach {Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName + " - Confidential" + $_.Extension }}
```

Thanks all for reading.

Comment: You need to include the path: `Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName {  $_.BaseName + " - Confidential"...`

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Sorry, could you please clarify? Do I need to specify the path or just add the -Path parameter?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Adding the path doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala suggestion should work.  Did you enter `-Path $_.FullName` as he suggested?  You can also remove the `ForEach` and pipe directly to `Rename-Item` in which case you can omit the Path.  `Get-ChildItem * -Exclude *Confidential* -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName + ' - Confidential' + $_.Extension }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but there's a few problems:

1. `Rename-Item` is missing the original file, so let's add `$_` to it. We could have also given it `$_.FullName` but I'm just passing the entire object to it.
2. `Rename-Item` is being given a script block with no input for `-NewName` because you've used curly braces (`{}`), so we change it to regular brackets (`()`).
3. Subfolders are also being renamed, which also results in files in them not being recursed (because they contain *Confidential*), so we specify the `-File` switch on `Get-ChildItem` to only return files.

So that brings us to this:

```
Get-ChildItem * -File -Exclude *Confidential* -Recurse | 
  ForEach {Rename-Item $_ -NewName ( $_.BaseName + " - Confidential" + $_.Extension )}
```

And just some cleanup/optimisation:

1. Remove wildcard (`*`) from `Get-ChildItem`. It already assumes all items in the folder you're in.
2. Enclose string in quote marks.
3. Add some spaces inside script block and change `ForEach` alias to shorter `%` alias (both just my personal preference).

And the final result looks like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Exclude "*Confidential*" -Recurse | 
  % { Rename-Item $_ -NewName ( $_.BaseName + " - Confidential" + $_.Extension ) }
```

As always, you can do a dry run by specifying `-WhatIf` on `Rename-Item`, just in case there's some unexpected behaviour.

**Edit:** You could actually just pipe the output of `Get-ChildItem` into `Rename-Item` like so without the need for `ForEach-Object`:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Exclude "*Confidential*" -Recurse | 
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName + " - Confidential" + $_.Extension }
```